# Playframework JSON Inheritance

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Hey guys I have a problem, I cannot serialize the BaseEntity properties to mongodb, it only serialize the (email,name,password) and creates the _id field.

Here is the code:

```
trait Entity[K] {
  val id: K
  val createDate: DateTime
  val updateDate: DateTime
}

class BaseEntity extends Entity[String] {
  val id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
  val createDate: DateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)
  val updateDate: DateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)
}

case class User(name: String, email: String, password: String) extends BaseEntity

object User {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[User]
}

#ReactiveMongo to insert the document
 def create(entity: E)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[E]] = {
    val doc = Json.toJson(entity).as[JsObject]

    this.collection.flatMap(_.insert(doc)).flatMap(_ => Future.successful(Option(entity)))
}
```

Comment: As indicated in the [requirements](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Requirements) of Play JSON, the automatic mapping is based on the `apply`/`unapply` functions, not to arbitrary `val`/`def`. Only `apply` parameters are mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a writes or format yourself

```
implicit val writes: Writes[User] = new Writes[User] {
    def writes(user: User): JsObject = Json.obj(
        "id" -> user.id,
        "createDate" -> user.createDate.toString,
        "updateDate" -> user.updateDate.toString,
        "name" -> user.name,
        "email" -> user.email,
        "password" -> user.password
    )
}
```

Comment: Better to consider `OWrites` rather than `Writes`, to keep object specificity. The syntax `OWrites[User] { user => .. }` (rather than defining completely an anonymous class) is available.